# How Can i set google map marker color randomly?

Tags: javascript

i am beginner in javascript now i am working in tracking application project.now i want to change google map marker color randomly.here is my code

```
if(type == 'user')
          {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
             icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png',
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
        }
        else
        {
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
             icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png',
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
           // var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(point);

        }

          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

i getting lot of user in same color in google map.now i want to change marker color randomly.any one please help  me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an array with multiple colors.
- Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * SIZE_OF_ARRAY) + 1` to generate the value.
- Use that random value to select the color dynamically from your value array.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array with all src you can have

```
var icons = ["http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png",
            "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png",
         ...etc
];
```

and in the `icon:` you can put `items[Math.floor(Math.random()*icons .length)]`

Comment: its Working Well Thanx @Bara's ayyash